# How to deserialize with RestSharp when I have an attribute named "value"?

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am using RestSharp to deserialize a XML file where some of the nodes are like this:

```
<element value="something" />
```

The elementes with an attribute called 'value' will not deserialize. Any ideas on how to get RestShap to deserialize this?

The object used to deserialize is like:

```
public class Object
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Please note, the XML is returned from a web service so I do not have the option of changing the attribute name to something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have found a solution. I think this is somewhat an edge case.

I renamed the variable

```
public string Value {get;set;}
```

to

```
public string value {get;set;}
```

And now it deserializes perfectly. Guess the Uppercase Value is for the value contained in a XML element only.

Comment: Edge case indeed. I'm glad you figured it out!